# vertx build with graalvm

Tags: vert.x, graalvm

I fallowed https://github.com/vertx-howtos/graal-native-image-howto/blob/20.3.0/README.adoc and manage to build my vertx project with graalvm, but when I start the native image vertx is not starting. I can not see vertx logs, "listening on..."

You can see my [full pom here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/test-microservice-frameworks/blob/main/vertx/pom.xml)

And java code [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/test-microservice-frameworks/blob/main/vertx/src/main/java/com/mascix/vertx_test/MainVerticle.java#L103)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding some error handling to the application will show that the 1st problem is related to missing the file `application.properties` from the image, this can be fixed by updating the `native-image.properties` config with:

```
-H:IncludeResources=.*\\.properties
```

Then the application will start but again will fail to return data. This is because the application is using jackson databind (which relies on reflection) to encode the POJO to JSON.

Fixing it requires some understanding on how jackson reflection works and write the correct configuration, or just keep it simple and use Vert.x built in JSON types, for example:

```
        req.response()
         .putHeader("content-type", "application/json")
         .end(new JsonObject()
           .put("name", "vertx")
           .put("releaseYear", LocalDate.now().getYear())
           .encode());
```

Comment: "Adding some error handling to the application will show that the 1st problem" what error handling ? vertx was not throwing any exception

Comment: I manage to use reflection and jackson, here is vertx result https://ozkanpakdil.github.io/microservicetests/2022-05-16-microservice-framework-test-11.html#graalvm-native-vertx-rest-service

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit, by error handling I meant:

`Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(new MainVerticle()).onFailure(Throwable::printStackTrace)`

That showned me that a NPE was being thrown when trying to read the properties file.